# Display list of custom dimensions in LookerStudio from Firebase Analytics event

Tags: swift, firebase, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I'm writing a mobile application in Swift and would like to create a Looker Studio table to see a list of the most popular locations selected in the app.

I have a custom Firebase Analytics event named `location_selected` which has a custom parameter of `id` which is sent as an Integer. I would like a list of these parameters in a table in Looker Studio so I can see which of them is the most popular.

The problem is that in Looker Studio, the ID definiton is just displayed as null or (not set) in the table instead of listing out various IDs that have been sent.

I think it might be something to do with sending the IDs as Integers but that doesn't seem right to me as I think I read somewhere that you custom definitions can be a String or Int.

#### The steps I followed:

1. Send event in Swift like so:

```
Analytics.logEvent("location_selected", parameters: ["id": 1])
```

2. Created a custom dimension (not metric) in Firebase called Location ID which referenced the "id: parameter and is scoped as event
3. Linked Firebase as a data source to Looker Studio
4. Created a Looker Studio table
5. Selected Location ID as the dimension
6. Selected Event Count as the metric
7. Filtered by the location_selected event
8. Observe [Looker Studio table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z13Cg.png)

#### Things I have ensured / done:

- Verified the events and parameters get shown in the Firebase realtime debug view [Debug view events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc5Ot.png)
- Edited the data source in looker studio to explicitly state Location ID is a number [Data source settings for Location ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgkC6.png)
- Setup the custom dimension, waited 24 hours, sent events, waited another 24 hours [Dimension definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP6NV.png)